# Can you find formulas that are infinitely close to disproving Fermat's last theorem?

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification

Is it possible for any given $\epsilon >0$ and $n > 2$ to find $x, y, z$ such that $$|x^n + y^n - z^n| < \epsilon, \textbf{[question 1]}$$

and if so, would this disprove FLT? [**question 2]**

After all, in order to prove that the infinite sum of some numbers $\sum a_n$ is equal to $S$, all that is needed to prove is that 'eventually', 'at the end', we get to $S$.

But by the same reasoning, if question 1 has an affirmative answer, then that would mean that 'eventually', 'in the end', Fermat's last theorem fails, and therefore, it cannot be true.

Comment: It's not possible for $\epsilon=1$.

Comment: `find x,y,z such that` What are *your* $x,y,z$ and $n$ assumed to be? If positive integers, then the answer is trivially negative. Otherwise, it's not related to Fermat's last theorem.

Comment: There are theorems saying, that the minimal $\epsilon$ increases with $n$ *(I think: if not $x,y,z \in \{0,1\}$ )*

Comment: Consider this: We currently know that Fermat's last theorem has been proven true. Therefore, the answer to at least one of your questions must be "no."

Answer (score 1):

Note that since $x$, $y$, and $z$ are integers, for $n > 2$ you will not be able to make $\epsilon = 1$ and have it still work out.